# Sentence Construction: "Which players will be part of a squad today?"

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, sentence-structure

I have situation wherein out of the two sports team I'm in a dilemma which players will be a part of their respective teams. The players may or may not be a part of their respective teams due to various reasons.

Is this correct gramatically "It's really difficult to judge which players will be a part of squad today (talking of both the sides).

Is there a better way of saying so?

P.S. The sport is cricket.

Comment: In AmE you could say, if you were the coach, "It's hard to decide who to start today" or "who to play today".  A coach can "start" a player, that is, put him or her in the game when it begins. Those players are the "starters".  Or a coach can "play" a player", that is, put him or her into the game at some point, either as a substitute for a player who is taken out of the game, or as a starter. Sometimes in context "to play" a player means to start a player.

Comment: If players could be chosen by either team or not chosen at all (not your case), you would say "It's difficult to judge which players will be part of *which* squad today."

Comment: Or "part of either squad", or anything similar to make it clear you're talking about both squads rather than just one.

Answer (score 1):

Your original sentence is reasonable, though should contain "each":

*"It's really difficult to judge which players will be a part of each squad today"*

A cricket "squad" is probably going to be all the players who could be chosen from to play an individual game ([example](https://www.kiaoval.com/squad/)), so you might use team, line-up or first eleven. You could use "selection", but that might give the impression of referring to Selectors choosing an international squad ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_cricket_selectors)).

Perhaps use chosen since that's what Captains and Coaches do (they choose from the squad):

*"It's really difficult to judge which players will be chosen today by each team"*

Though I this is not much better than the sentence you started with - perhaps stick with writing the way you are happy to write.

Comment: ***part of a squad*** sounds a bit weird to me in this context. *It's really difficult to judge which players will be **in** each squad today.* I don't like ***judge*** either, but I don't know exactly what meaning is intended, so *maybe* that's "acceptable".